# Case Insensitive Search with g ex command?

Tags: ex-mode, letter-case

How can you do a case insensitive search with line contexts displayed in vim while using the `:g` ex command?

I tried the following but it doesn't seem to work...

```
g/pattern/z#.1i|echo "================================"
```

I also tried this:

```
g/pattern/iz#.1|echo "================================"
```

...but it results in an error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

*One* is to `set ignorecase`, then the pattern regex will ignore the case.  Yet, this solution is poor if you are writing a script that may need to be reused by someone.

A *better solution* is to use the `\c` (ignore case) `\C` (do not ignore case) modifiers in the regex.  This command:

```
g/\cpattern/z#.1|echo "================================"
```

Will always ignore the case of `pattern` no matter what you have set `ignorecase` to.

And this command:

```
g/\Cpattern/z#.1|echo "================================"
```

Will always perform a case sensitive search for `pattern`, even if you have `ignorecase` set to true.

Reference (the forward slash is important):

- `:help /ignorecase`

Answer (score 2):

You can do a `set ic` before the search command.